# Onboard recording of trans-Mars injection

Tags: spacex, falcon-heavy

Is there any video recording of the Falcon Heavy trans-Mars injection burn from onboard cameras?

The live feed of the Tesla Roadster and Starman orbiting Earth cycled through multiple cameras including a couple facing the engine. Before the live feed started it was reported that there would be battery capacity for 12 hours and the craft would be coasting for 6 hours before the trans-Mars injection burn.

Given all of the above it seems like a live broadcast of the trans-Mars injection burn may have been planned.

Were the onboard cameras expected to record the trans-Mars injection burn? Did such a recording happen?

Comment: As far as all the media that SpaceX has released at this point in time, there is no public video of this burn however that doesn't mean it doesn't exist